# Did not or Would not

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs

I have a question please. In the next sentence:

I wish John lived close.

1. So we didn't have to walk this far.
2. So we wouln't have to walk this far.
3. So we wouldn't walked this far.

Which one is correct? what is the difference? I hope someone could help me, thanks.

Comment: #1 is only suitable if we ***did in fact*** make the (shorter) walk. Idiomatically, native speakers will often use #2 in the same context, but strictly speaking ***would*** strongly implies a ***hypothetical / future*** situation - we haven't (yet) done the walk at all, regardless of whether something has been done so it is / will be shorter than it ***would have been***.

Comment: ***this far*** implies we're currently walking, so ***didn't*** is better. If it had been ***that far***, probably ***wouldn't*** would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two are correct and the third is incorrect.

The practical reality is that the two statements are interchangeable. You could use either one and nobody would question you. Technically, there is a slight difference between **did** and **would**.

The difference between **did** and **would** has to do with whether you've started walking. In general, you use **did** to describe something that actually happened in the past. You use **would** to describe something that's hypothetical or that might happen. You can also use it to introduce doubt about whether something will continue to happen. For example:

> I wish John lived close so we didn't have to walk this far.

The implication is that you've already started walking.

> I wish John lived close so we wouldn't have to walk this far.

The implication is that you haven't started walking yet, and you might decide not to walk. Or, if you've started walking, you can use that statement to introduce doubt about whether you will continue to walk.

You can use **didn't** to describe something that hasn't happened yet only if you change **this** to **that**. For example:

> I wish John lived close so we **didn't** have to walk **that** far.

To further confuse things,  **would** is also a past tense form of **will**. For example:

> John lives close, so he will walk here.
>
> John lived close, so he would walk here.

The use of **would** does **not** introduce any uncertainty or doubt. It's simply a past tense form of **will**.

Comment: ***didn't*** can also imply the walking was in the ***past***, not "ongoing". As opposed to ***wouldn't***, which can imply the walking ***hasn't yet started*** (it might start in a minute, or next week).

Comment: Agreed, I just didn't include an example for that usage.

Comment: I didn't read your entire answer carefully enough first time around, but I see now my earlier comment under the actual question just repeats exactly the point you make re changing ***this*** to ***that***.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend Sentence (1).

Sentence (2) is influenced by the conditional - "**If** John lived closer to us we wouldn't have to walk so far." The meaning is clear, but as there is no 'if' it would be better not to use *wouldn't.*

Sentence (3) is just plain ungrammatical - you can't say *wouldn't walked.*

Answer (score -1):

Choice 3 as pointed out by @KateBunting is ungrammatical. It's outright incorrect.

I consider the first two choices correct, usage-wise, although I would personally lean towards choice 2 (wouldn't have).

I'm not sure I agree with @KateBunting on the other point though. Sentence 2 may or may not have been influenced by the conditional but it is not relevant to our discussion.

The right question to ask, in my opinion, is whether our verb should agree with "so" (which is part of the same clause) or with the earlier-occurring "wish".

To me all the following are correct:

*I wish John lived close by.

I wish we didn't have to walk so far.

I wish John lived close by. Then we wouldn't have to walk so far.

I wish John lived close by, so (that) we wouldn't have to walk so far.*
Also:
*I wish John lived close by, so (that) we didn't have to walk so far.*

To back up the above, here are some examples from different sources and an Ngram:

> *She worked hard so that everything would be ready in time.* (Oxford)
> *He lowered his voice so no one would hear.* (Macmillan)

---

[image]